# error in inflating class

Tags: android, android-inflate, inflate-exception

I have problem but I don't know what's it.
I always wrote this code and it work correctly but this time it doesn't work.

error:

```
10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Book4000eew1/com.Book4000eew1.Lessons}:
                                                    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.Book4000eew1.Lessons.onCreate(Lessons.java:13)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     ... 11 more
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     ... 23 more
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
    10-27 07:40:52.769: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     ... 26 more
```

and this is my lessons class:

```
public class Lessons extends ListActivity{

    private Integer[] lessonspics={};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lessons);   


    }


}
```

and it's xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/n9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

does any one know what is my problem????
thanks in advance.

Comment: You're getting an `OutOfMemoryError` when it's trying to load an image. I would guess your `@drawable/n9` is too big.

Comment: As in log `BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset` method `n9` image size is very big which is not rendering in current available memory.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that. The image was too big.

Answer (score 0):

Inside ListView

**Instead of This :**

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

**Do this :**

```
android:id="@+id/your ID"
```

Comment: it should be android:id="@+id/your ID"

Comment: that was a typing mistake you got the point thats good enough i guess :)

Comment: That's ok but  it's for OP's understanding and it's possible that he may make a mistake again :)

Comment: Its not fair to Down Vote without any explanation, at least correct me so next time I can not repeat that while helping

Comment: I was the one to upvote it very first time.And yes one should provide the reason for downvote.

Comment: Please go through the log. its says that error caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. This is not the right answer to the question.

Comment: & if its not the right answer you think then Click the Answer button & give your best short as I pointed what I think, let us see your answer, there is no restriction that a question can only have one answer

Comment: "the First Cause inside Log" indicates line #2, which is the LinearLayout. Sunny is correct. The ListView's ID is not the problem. That is a perfectly valid ID.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this in your Android manifest File

```
<activity android:name=".Lessons" > </activity>
```

also it seems you have null value of list should define a listview in the layout file and assign it a unique ID.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >
```

From the onCreate method of an Activity, find the Listview with corresponding id

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

if still doesn't work show more codes then will try to solve it.